# Which method would be better to use on VB.net?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, split, listboxitem

Im trying to understand which method would be better to split an incoming message that will be sent over a chat application. the delimiter is ^ that will split it into a string array.

one method is this way:

```
lsIncommingtext.Items.Add(lblContactName.Text & " ^ " & Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") & " ^ " & Now.ToString("hh:mm") & " ^ " & txtChatbar.Text)
```

the second method would be:

```
Dim lineparts() As String
lineparts = line.Split("^")
txtName.Text = lineparts(0)
txtAddip.Text = lineparts(1)
```

Im trying to make the end message to be in the format of:
**SendersName^DateSent^TimeSent^MessageData**

With each of these ^, used to split the incoming message.

Comment: You better use a "stranger" separator, such as **§**. Something which is unlikely to be used in a chat message.

Comment: @DerGolem: A chat program that excludes lawyers?  I'm in!

Answer (score 1):

Neither method is ideal.

If the user types `4 ^ 2 = 16` then your payload gets all screwed up.  What you want to do is create a format what will survive all user input as well as data fragmentation.

*for example*
Make the first byte of the message be the message type (e.g. 1=String message, 2=System Updates, 3=File transfer, 4=Visibility status updates... yadda eider).

The next 8-bytes (Int64) will be the payload length.  This tells you how many bytes you need to read from the `NetworkStream` before you have the complete message.  Int64 is good if you are going to be doing file transfers.  For everything else Int32 (4-bytes) will be fine.

Now comes the payload.  Payload can be anything you like as long as it ends after the length defined earlier - because your next message begins immediately after the end of the payload.

Comment: In terms of splitting strings into arrays which is the most efficient way of approaching this?

Comment: Yeah - I'm not going to help you make a mess.  Especially since you've already written the code and are capable of testing it yourself.